# run command line contains redirection >> inside Guest VM

Tags: command-line-interface, virtualbox, io-redirection

To run `ls -l /home` for example in Guest VM called `myvm` , we can run on the host :

```
vboxmanage --nologo guestcontrol myvm --username root --password xxxx run  --exe /bin/ls --wait-stdout --wait-stderr -- ls/arg0 -l /home
```

Now , if we try to run this command `echo "this is new line " >> /home/u1/sample.txt` using the same methodology :

```
vboxmanage --nologo guestcontrol myvm --username root --password xxxx run  --exe /bin/echo --wait-stdout --wait-stderr -- echo/arg0 "this is new line " >> /home/u1/sample.txt
```

--> I've got :

> bash: /home/u1/sample.txt : No such file or  .

i add quotes :

```
vboxmanage --nologo guestcontrol myvm --username root --password xxxx run  --exe /bin/echo --wait-stdout --wait-stderr -- echo/arg0 '"this is new line " >> /home/u1/sample.txt'
```

-->  Nothing has been changed in the Guest VM , i mean `/home/u1/sample.txt` .

### Any idea ? known that i use VirtualBox 5.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since :

```
command > redirect
```

is similar to :

```
/bin/sh -c "command > redirect"
```

Then :

```
vboxmanage --nologo guestcontrol myvm --username root --password xxxx run  --exe /bin/sh --wait-stdout --wait-stderr -- sh/arg0 -c "echo this is new line >> /home/u1/sample.txt"
```